# Measuring very fast operations like add?

Tags: c++

I'm really unsure where to post this. Is code review better?

I'm trying to measure the time it takes for unordered_set to do a lookup. I get reasonable values with the includes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>
```

And the code (warning more than 40 lines of code)

```
std::vector<int> eurastothenes_sieve(size_t count){
    std::vector<bool> sieve(count * std::log2(count), true);
    sieve[0] = false;
    sieve[1] = false;
    auto factor = 2;
    while(factor * factor < sieve.size()) {
        for (auto not_prime_idx = factor * 2; not_prime_idx < sieve.size(); not_prime_idx+= factor) {
            sieve[not_prime_idx] = false;
        }
        while(!sieve[++factor]);
    }
    std::vector<int> primes;
    for(int idx = 0; idx < sieve.size(); idx++){
        if(sieve[idx]){
            primes.push_back(idx);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

std::vector<int> numbers_to_find(int max, size_t count) {
    std::vector<int> v(count);
    auto p_rand = [max](){
        return std::rand() % max;
    };
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), p_rand);
    return v;
}

int main() {
    auto primes = eurastothenes_sieve(1000);
    std::unordered_set<decltype(primes)::value_type> primeset(primes.begin(), primes.end());

    std::map<int, double> timings;

    for(int i = 100; i <= 1000; i+=100 ){
        auto find_me = numbers_to_find(primes[i], 10000);
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto found = 0;
        int count = 10000;
        while(count--)
        for(auto val: find_me)
        {
            if(primeset.find(val) != primeset.end()){
                found++;
            }
        }

        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        std::cout << "In " << (end - start).count() << " ns";
        std::cout << " we found " << found << "\n";
        timings.insert({i, (end - start).count() / (10000.0 * 10000)});
    }
    for(auto n_t : timings){
        std::cout << "N = " << n_t.first << ": " << n_t.second << "ns\n";
    }
}
```

The results are

```
N = 100: 15.5874ns
N = 200: 15.4113ns
N = 300: 15.3488ns
N = 400: 15.4806ns
N = 500: 15.4009ns
N = 600: 15.5415ns
N = 700: 15.3537ns
N = 800: 15.4371ns
N = 900: 15.2567ns
N = 1000: 15.3602ns
```

Then i tried to measure how the measure how much the measurement apparatus contributed to this so I tried doing a trivial operation that couldn't be optimized out. :

```
    for(auto val: find_me)
    {
            found+=val;         
    }
```

A trivial operation. Now I get

```
N = 100: 0.0657845ns
N = 200: 0.0657359ns
N = 300: 0.0649369ns
N = 400: 0.0651398ns
N = 500: 0.0649169ns
N = 600: 0.0650553ns
N = 700: 0.0654992ns
N = 800: 0.0645845ns
N = 900: 0.065315ns
N = 1000: 0.0649747ns
```

I am measuring the time for one or two very simple operations.

The title is misleading insofar I'd like to understand the actual timings.

Step 1: yes unordered_set is O(1) access. That's nice and expected. My setup creates no difficulties.

Why is a mod and a memory lookup(unordered map) 200 times more costly than

Step 2: register + cached value?

Is this code actually adding a random integer every 0.06 nanosecond?

In conclusion
Why is a mod and a memory lookup so expensive?

I tried to be cache friendly. My L1 cache is 32K.

`CMake -release` `g++ -O2`

Comment: If you are looking for performance, you are not going to want to use the standard unordered containers.  Because of their requirements they basically need to be implemented as a `std::vector<std::list<T>>`, which will generally cause at least one cache miss every access since it's all pointer indirection in a linked list.

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed, I'll try the same with an std::vector<SimpleLink*>. I was just surprised with the 200x slowdown.

Comment: You should measure larger sets to see where the L1, L2, L3 caches make the process go slower. If you don't find any slowdowns then you are measurement is broken. I assume i=100 fits in L1 cache. But it certainly should be in L2 and L3 cache.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I want it to fit in L1. It does go slower in L3, that is no surprise. With enough space to also fit `find_me`.

Comment: Sure. But seeing it drop in speed as the L1/L2/L3 limits are reached is a good indicator your actually measuring what you thing you measure. It will also highlight such thing as the unordered_map always having an indirection as that doubles the cache usage and will slow down quicker than you thought. So I recommend always measuring where those cache limits are even if just to verify your assumptions about how much memory is used.